# Call a method only after jobs on other threads have terminated?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous, .net-4.5

in my app I have two methods that load data from csv. These methods are `loadData()` and `loadOtherData()`. I want to run them in parallel so I have two threads to run them.

The `loadData()` method also populate one datagridview, while the data loaded by the `loadOtherData()` method are stored in a dictionary `myDictionary`.

After data loading is completed (so the methods running in the two threads have finished) I want to call another method `updateGrids()` that takes `myDictionary` as argument.

For `updateGrids()` to run properly, both `loadData()` and `loadOtherData()` must have run successfully cause otherwise the method doesn't have the data to work on.

How can I call method `updateGrids()` only when the other methods have terminated in other threads?

The structure is as follow:

```
    private void loadData_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadStart thread1Start = new ThreadStart(loadData); // load data and fill the first datagridview
        ThreadStart thread2Start = new ThreadStart(loadOtherData); // load data and fill myDictionary
        Thread t1 = new Thread(thread1Start);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(thread2Start);
        t1.Start(); 
        t2.Start();

        updateGrids(myDictionary); // call this method to update remaining datagridviews
    }


    private void updateGrids(Dictionary<string, double> myDictionary)
    {
        // update the remaining datagridviews by using 
        // information in the first datagridview and in myDictionary
    }
```

But if I run this, I get the error when `updateGrids()` since it doesn't have the data to work with. How can I easily change the code to make it work?

Comment: All working threads should provide possibility to check if they finished their job (simple counter will do). At the end of their job they should call a method which checks if all thread jobs are finished and invoke `updateGrid()`.

Comment: What version of .Net are you using? That can affect the answers.

Comment: Thanks, added now in the title. I am using 4.5

Comment: I removed it from the title; tags are the preferred place for details like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [async/await](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) to wait both tasks without blocking the UI

```
async private void loadData_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.WhenAll(Task.Run(() => loadData()), 
                       Task.Run(() => loadOtherData()));

    updateGrids(myDictionary); 
}
```

Comment: Do I need to declare loadData() and loadOtherData( as async in order to run in parallel?

Comment: @mickG No, I assumed them as `void xxx()`

Comment: Thanks, this works as expected. Is it the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: @mickG *"best way"* can be very subjective. But I think so.

Comment: I see, can you confirm that this won't run on older .NET version?

Comment: (very) stupid question: is it really working on more threads? Because when I run and look at the resource monitor it seems that only one CPU is used.

Comment: @mickG If  your methods do many IO, you won't see much CPU activities.

Answer (score 2):

You could stop using ThreadStart objects directly and use Tasks instead - have them returned from your loadData and loadOtherData methods.

You have either two options here:

Either Use Task.WaitAll if you're using .NET 4.0

or (more preferable)....

Make loadData and loadOtherData async in .NET 4.5 and above (or use the async BCL package in .NET 4.0). The when you call the methods, you can cache the Task objects they return and await a call to Task.WhenAll

```
public async Task LoadData(){ 

}

public async Task LoadOtherData() {

}

private async void loadData_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var loadDataTask = LoadData();
    var loadOtherDataTask = LoadOtherData();
    await Task.WhenAll(loadDataTask, loadOtherDataTask);

    updateGrids(myDictionary);
}
```

Comment: I don't see a downvote, but since the OP isn't using async / await you don't fully answer the question.  Its fine to suggest an alternative, but the OP may be more comfortable with Thread and you should answer how to do this with that as well.

Comment: The downvote has since been removed. The OP is using .NET 4.5.

Comment: I don't see how it matters that he's using .Net 4.5.  His question is how to get this working with Thread, so you should answer THAT question.  Suggest async / await if you like, but its not like there's anything wrong with using Thread (which has a LOT for info about it since its been around much longer).

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand your point. Tasks implicitly use threads in the CLR. Although his original question contains a snippet using Thread objects, he does not say he is constrained by this. Using async/await and Tasks in .NET 4.5 is more conventional than using Thread objects natively and will also make his life easier handling exceptional cases.

Answer (score -1):

After you start your threads, you want to wait until they are done.  So add these lines of code:

```
t1.Join();
t2.Join();
```

[Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta(v=vs.110).aspx) will cause the current thread to sleep until the thread being joined is complete.

Based on comments, I'm assuming this is WinForms.  In this case `Join` will block the UI thread.  You could create a third thread that will join the other two threads and then call [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) to call your update method.

Since you're using .Net 4.5., you could use Async / Await; add the `async` modifier to your click method event handler and uses Tasks instead of Threads directly and `await` them.  Other answers cover that, and you can see this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2013/12/18/c-async-and-await-why-do-we-need-them-part-1.aspx) for other details too.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as expected. I tried but the app becomes non responsive and I need to stop the program.

Comment: @Sinatr how is "create a third thread which will join the other two threads and then call Invoke" not a complete solution?  If he did that, it would work as expected.  Or do you think I should write the code for him?